# Arraylist<hashmap<>> values repeating in listview

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to get the contents of a Sqlite database into a listview using simple adapter.
I am using a arraylist> to get all the values. It is getting displayed on the listview but the values seem to repeat everytime i run it.
what should i do?
Here's my code

```
             ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>val=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
              Databasehandler db=new Databasehandler(this);

              private ListView lv;
                  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.contacts);
             val=db.getAllContacts();
                   final ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);


               if(val.size()!=0)
                {
             ListAdapter ad=new SimpleAdapter(Contact.this,val,R.layout.v,new String[]{"contacts"},new int[]{R.id.textView2});

               lv.setAdapter(ad);
           }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare the ArrayList before onCreate method like...

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>val = null;
```

And initialize this ArrayList when you want put retrieved values into the ArrayList like...

```
val=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
```

Comment: how to remove identical values from a hashmap?

Answer (score 1):

I think, problem is in your list adapter(Simple Adapter). Please check your list adapter's getView() is add twise of view, just check out your adapter with following...

Just use this custom adapter,

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<SearchObjects> mObjects = null;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;

    public CustomAdapter (Context context, List<SearchObjects> mData) {
        mObjects = mData;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return mObjects.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mObjects.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         ViewHolder holder;
         if (convertView == null) 
         {
              convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.search_items_single_row,null);
              holder = new ViewHolder();
              holder.txtvName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtvItemName);
              convertView.setTag(holder);
         } 
         else
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
         holder.txtvName.setText(mObjects.get(position).getDL_TRADENAME());
         return convertView;
     }

     private class ViewHolder {
         TextView txtvName = null;
     }
}
```

& call it as,

```
mCustomListAdapter = new RxNewSearchDrugsListAdapter(getActivity(), mSearchObjects);
mListView.setAdapter(mCustomListAdapter );
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your db .Does it have duplicate values???

If not - try adding values in Arraylist only if they do not exist already in the list

```
for(each..str){
if(!myArrList.contains(str)){
myArrList.add(str);
}
```

**EDIT**

Since you face the prob when you re run it .Make sure the database does not repopulate rows with save values 
**OR**

just reinitialize your arraylists .eg `myArrList = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: database doesnt have repeated values